# How to do distinct by first column

Tags: sql, distinct

```
Select DISTINCT wpg.ID as id1,wr.ID as id2
FROM Table1 wpg
inner join Table2 wp ON wp.WpgId = wpg.ID
inner join Table3 wr ON wr.WpId = wp.ID
```

I need wpg.Id distinct how do this?

I need  from:

> 1 2
>
> 2 3
>
> 1 4

get:

> 1 2
>
> 2 3

Comment: When wpg.ID isn't distinct, which wr.ID do you want?  Does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on what you want to do with the second column. I'm assuming you want the smallest value:

```
select
    wpg.ID as id1,
    min(wr.ID) as id2
from
    Table1 wpg
    inner join Table2 wp on wp.WpgId = wpg.ID
    inner join Table3 wr on wr.WpId = wp.ID
group by
    wpg.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select wpg.ID, min(wr.ID)
FROM Table1 wpg 
inner join Table2 wp ON wp.WpgId = wpg.ID 
inner join Table3 wr ON wr.WpId = wp.ID 
group by wpg.ID
```